# How to rename root repository folder?

Tags: github

I need to rename the root repository folder, for example: `github.com/Org/projectX` to `github.com/Org/projectY` Should I be using 'git mv'? or this can only be done by cloning and creating a new `projectY`?

Answer (score 4):

Github provides an option to rename a repository under 'settings'.  Once you have renamed the project on github you can clone it again.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that did the job!